# Global variables cannot be read by server.R in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The two files in ./app

## ui.R

```
library(shiny)

a <- 1
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("test")
)
```

## server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderText({
    a
  })
}
```

Run shiny app

```
shiny::runApp("app")
```

## Error

```
Warning: Error in cat: argument 1 (type 'closure') cannot be handled by 'cat'
  102: cat
   98: transform
   97: func
   95: f
   94: Reduce
   85: do
   84: hybrid_chain
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$test
    1: shiny::runApp
```

If I put the code in on file, it work. What is the reason for this?

```
library(shiny)

a <- 1
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderText({
    a
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: In a shiny application, you can use a `global.R` source file whose objects defined there will be visible to both `server.R` and `ui.R`.

Comment: You can put the variable in an extra .R file and call the file at the beginning (above ui).

Comment: In addition to @nicola's comment please check the section *Global objects* [here](https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/improve/scoping/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you dont have global file to call server and ui together, you need to merge ui and server in global, why your first app doesnt run is that `shiny::runApp()` is to run built beforehand app, but what I see your files you dont have any shinyapp, whereas if you want to create app you need to use complete all steps and add shinyApp() function as well. Therefore second code is working.

Check below solution

ui.R file

```
a <- 1
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("test")
)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$test <- renderText({
    a
  })
}
```

global.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(ui = source("app/ui.R")$value, server = source("app/server.R")$value)
```

if you want to use your app in different solution `shiny::runApp()`
then you can create one more file for example run.R

and paste:

```
shiny::runApp("path/global.R", host= "your IP address", port=1336)
```

and run this command in terminal, and your shiny app will be available online within your IP address unless closing your active terminal

```
"C:\Program Files\R\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "path\run.R"
```

Comment: There is no need to `source()` `ui.R` and `server.R` in `global.R`. `runApp()` only needs the `appDir` where the according files reside.

Comment: I had multiple apps in my project and default wd, so if there is one, then Appdir can be changed

Comment: For multiple apps in a single project I'd suggest using subdirectories for each app or to create shiny app objects (wrapped in functions) with global variables initialized in `shinyApp()`s `onStart` callback (see `?onStop` for an example). However, this is pretty niche and not what OP asked for.